# HTML - optimize Change dropdown to list in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, list, drop-down-menu

It is possible to change dropdown to list in form?

> can't embed an image because of the reputation

here's my form with dropdown :
[image: dropdown]

then I've change the value inside dropdown to list like this:
[image: dropdown to list]

but the problem, my first image can execute the button and save the value, but when I change the form interface like my 2nd image, the button can't execute (nothing effect showing after clicking the button)

my code on dropdown looks like :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="ik">Kriteria</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="ik" name="ik">
    <?php
    $stmt2 = $pgn2->readAll();
    while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    extract($row2);
      echo "<option value='{$id_kriteria}'>{$nama_kriteria}</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

then I change the code of `<select>` to `<form>` like this to showing list :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <form class="form-control" id="ik" name="ik">
    <?php
    $stmt2 = $pgn2->readAll();
    while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      extract($row2);
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $id_kriteria; ?>"><?php echo $nama_kriteria; ?></option>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nn" name="nn">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </form>
</div>
```

***Problem:***

the 2nd code is `<form>` inside `<form>`, because if I change the `<form>` tag to `<label>` or etc, the interface looks bad,

may someone help me how to do?

Comment: `<option>` must be inside `<select>`

Comment: @A.Lau so there's a way to change `<option>` sir?

Comment: It is not clear what you want by putting `<option>` outside of a `<select>`

Comment: @A.Lau the point is, i want to detect each `input` depending on `$nama_kriteria`, so if i'm input 80, 79, 79, 80, how to make the button know as `1, 80 ; 2, 79 ; 3, 79 ; 4, 80 ;??

Comment: then just use `input type='text'` or `input type=number`?